# Cannot find name 'angular.module'

Tags: angular, syntax-error

I am trying to follow some of tutorial for Angular and the sample code has

```
let app = angular.module("demo", []);
```

However, there is an typescript error for 'angular' and [ts] Cannot find name 'angular'.[2304]

How can I solve this problem? I am very new to Angular and using Angular 7.

Please, help me if you know solution.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: That tutorial is probably for AngularJS (version 1.x). You should find a tutorial for Angular 7 (or at least for Angular 2+).

Comment: i think u are follow Angular js tutorial please make sure to use angular 7 tutorial. follow this site (https://angular.io)

Comment: Oh, I found it is posted in 2014. Thank you guys. I will find angular 7 tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That doesn't look like Angular code, that looks like Angular JS code.

Use this tutorial to help you get started with Angular: https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

Install Node then run these commands

> npm install -g @angular/cli

Move into the folder you want to make your project and replace my-app with the name you prefer.

> ng new my-app

cd into your new project and run

> ng serve --open

This will open your new project on http://localhost:4200/